# Getting and putting Json into Pojo class

Tags: java, json, api, retrofit2, spotify

So I've made an app that should be able to search for an artist off the Spotify API. The response returns a 200 code. But the returned object is null. Meaning that either the response code should be 204 or that something is wrong with my class. The class is made with pojo and seems right. 
I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Here are the code.

Artist Class

```java
public class Artists {

    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    private String href;
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<Item> items;
    @SerializedName("limit")
    @Expose
    private Integer limit;
    @SerializedName("next")
    @Expose
    private String next;
    @SerializedName("offset")
    @Expose
    private Integer offset;
    @SerializedName("previous")
    @Expose
    private String previous;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private Integer total;

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Integer getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(Integer limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public String getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(String next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Integer getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    public void setOffset(Integer offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    public Object getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setPrevious(String previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Artists{" +
                "href='" + href + '\'' +
                ", items=" + items +
                ", limit=" + limit +
                ", next='" + next + '\'' +
                ", offset=" + offset +
                ", previous='" + previous + '\'' +
                ", total=" + total +
                '}';
    }
```

Item Class

```java
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("external_urls")
    @Expose
    private ExternalUrls externalUrls;
    @SerializedName("followers")
    @Expose
    private Followers followers;
    @SerializedName("genres")
    @Expose
    private List<String> genres;
    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    private String href;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> images;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private Integer popularity;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("uri")
    @Expose
    private String uri;

    public ExternalUrls getExternalUrls() {
        return externalUrls;
    }

    public void setExternalUrls(ExternalUrls externalUrls) {
        this.externalUrls = externalUrls;
    }

    public Followers getFollowers() {
        return followers;
    }

    public void setFollowers(Followers followers) {
        this.followers = followers;
    }

    public List<String> getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(List<String> genres) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Image> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Integer popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

MainActivity

```java
public void searchForArtist(View view) {

        String q = "Justin Bieber";
        TrackService trackService = ApiUtils.getTrackService();
        Call<Artists> artistSearch = trackService.SearchForArtist("Bearer " + AuthToken, Accept, contentType, q, type, market, limit, offset);
        Log.d("TEST", artistSearch.request().url().toString());
        Log.d("TEST", " " + artistSearch.request().headers());
        Log.d("Tokens", AuthToken);
        Log.d("Tokens", " " + RefreshToken);
        artistSearch.enqueue(new Callback<Artists>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Artists> call, Response<Artists> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().getItems() != null) {
                        Item artists = response.body().getItems().get(0);
                        artistID = artists.getId();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yeehaw", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        searchForTracks(artistID);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No content in Items", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("BODY",response.body().toString());
                    }

                } else {
                    String message = "Problem " + response.code() + " " + response.body();
                    Log.d("Tracks", message);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Artists> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "REEEEEEEE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I added constructors to all classes. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try printing the raw response received from API?

Comment: Yes. I tried to do response.body().toString() and it returnes this Artists{id=null, name=null....} so I am kind of lost :D

Comment: Does Spotify API returns a response body when you hit via some other tool like postman?

Comment: Yes it does. That is what is the most odd to me. I use the same URL and the same Token in Postman, and it returns exactly what is exspected in the body